# Can't ssh from windows 11 to ubuntu PC on local network. I Can ssh from a windows PC to windows PC and ubuntu to windows, as well as IOS to ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, windows-11

I am trying to ssh from a Windows 11 PC into my Ubuntu PC over a local network.

I have followed the Microsoft OpenSSH tutorial to install the openssh client on the Windows 11 PC.

The PC with Ubuntu was installed today and has openssh server installed and running.

I am not able to ssh from my Windows 11 PC using openssh to the Ubuntu PC.

I am getting an error when running the below command in Powershell

"`ssh -vvv djserver1@192.168.x.xxx`"

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Rex/.ssh/config error:2

debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2

debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 192.168.x.xxx is address

debug2: ssh_connect_direct

debug1: Connecting to 192.168.x.xxx [192.168.x.xxx] port 22.

debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001C3532E8AE0

debug1: connect to address 192.168.x.xxx port 22: Connection timed out

ssh: connect to host 192.168.x.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

I can connect to the Ubuntu PC via ssh from my Iphone over the network.

I have checked my auth.log file on my Ubuntu machine as has been recommended in the comments.

The logs do not have any information about the unsuccessful ssh attempts from my Windows 11 PC, but when I make a successful ssh connection from my iPhone it is logged.

Comment: Please use the appropriate code tags for logs and commands.

Comment: Can you add the contents of the sshd log from your server?

Comment: So the Ubuntu machine cannot access either server?  So which machine is the errors with a username using a configuration file `C:/Users/Rex/.ssh/config` or `C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config`.  Password authentication or public-key authentication.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.  **After reading your question, 5 times, I am definitely confused by what is working and what isn't working.**

Comment: @mashuptwice I added the logs and tried to format the question better

Comment: @Ramhound Hey, apologies for the confusion. I tried to rewrite the question to make it more clear. When I try to ssh from the Windows 11 PC to the Ubuntu PC I get that error.

Comment: @DJBrittain The server log isn't very helpful without a correlation to the error. Please only post the **relevant** part of the log

Comment: @mashuptwice The thing is that the error I included above is produced in PowerShell on Windows when I attempt to ssh into the Ubuntu PC. I am not very familiar with the ubuntu logs so I am not sure what is relevant in the auth.log  to the error in Powershell.

Comment: @DJBrittain Relevant would be the section at which you try to login to the server and the error occurs. The log comes with timestamps which should make it easy for you to find the right part. It would be perfect if your client log and your server log would resemble the same incident.

Comment: @mashuptwice I just tested a failed connection from my Windows PC and then checked the auth.logs and nothing changed. I then made a connection from my Iphone which was successful and that was logged. It looks like failed ssh attempts are not recorded in auth.logs file

Comment: Sure they are, example from your log: `Failed password for djserver1 from 127.0.0.1 port 48614 ssh2`

Comment: What I'm trying to say is it is not necessary to have openssh installed to just ssh from Windows to an Ubuntu server. My answer was correct.

Comment: My understanding of the question was that you were trying to SSH from Windows to Ubuntu. I gave you the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had the my main pc connected to the modem, and the ubuntu pc connected to my router.